# Work command will not add money to user's wallet

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a working command and when I try it, the bot does not do anything nor say an error in the console. How can I get this to work? I also define `open_account` below.

```
async def open_account(user):
  users = await get_bank_data()

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
      return True
```

my get_bank_data code

```
async def get_bank_data():
  with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)

    return users

async def update_bank(user, change=0, mode="wallet"):
  users = await get_bank_data()

  users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

  with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

    bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"], users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
    return bal
```

my work command

```
@bot.command()
async def work(ctx):
  member = ctx.author
  await open_account(member)

  users = await get_bank_data()
  user = member
  money = random.randrange(0, 30)

  users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += money

  with open("bank.json") as f:
    json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

  embed=discord.Embed(title="Work", description=f"{ctx.author.name} went to work!", color=0x00FFFF)
  embed.add_field(name="You Earned:", value=f"{money} Ulti Coins", inline=False)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
  embed.set_footer(text="Your total amount is saved across all servers that I'm in!")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Where is `get_bank_data`?

Comment: @Dominik I edited the code so you can look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was that you opened the JSON file, but after step 3 (In my case the `print` functions) nothing happened.
This was because you did not `write` anything to the JSON file.

**You can fix this error by using the following function:**

```py
with open("bank.json", "w") as f: # w for writing
    json.dump(users, f)
```

**The full/new code could be:**

```py
@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    await open_account(member)
    print("Account opened")

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = member
    money = random.randrange(0, 30)
    print(f "Chosen amount {money}")

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += money
    print("Function works")

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f: # Changes here
        json.dump(users, f)
        print("Updates work")

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Work", description=f"{ctx.author.name} went to work!", color=0x00FFFF)
    embed.add_field(name="You Earned:", value=f"{money} Ulti Coins", inline=False)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text="Your total amount is saved across all servers that I'm in!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

- Next time you can build in `print` to actually see where the error occurs, this is a good method to get closer to the error.